# Edit 'My - Post Cycle' Wordpress widget to post only specific blog categories

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have a wordpress theme with a widget named 'My - Post Cycle', which allows me to post entries from my blog. I want to be able to select which post 'categories' are displayed with the widget. Having the 'category ID', how can I edit the widget PHP to only show the category IDs I choose. Here is the code:

```
<?php
// =============================== My Post Cycle widget ======================================
class MY_CycleWidget extends WP_Widget {
    /** constructor */
    function MY_CycleWidget() {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'My - Post Cycle');    
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::widget */
    function widget($args, $instance) {     
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
                $limit = apply_filters('widget_limit', $instance['limit']);
                $category = apply_filters('widget_category', $instance['category']);
                $count = apply_filters('widget_count', $instance['count']);
        ?>
              <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
                  <?php if ( $title )
                        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>

                        <?php if($category=="testi"){?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                    jQuery(function(){
                                        jQuery('#slides').slides({
                                            effect: 'fade',
                                            crossfade: true,
                                            preload: true,
                                            generateNextPrev: true,
                                            autoHeight: true
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                <div id="slides">
                                    <div class="slides_container">

                                    <?php $limittext = $limit;?>
                                    <?php global $more; $more = 0;?>
                                    <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=". $count ."&post_type=" . $category);?>

                                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

                                        <?php 
                                        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                                        $testiname = $custom["my_testi_caption"][0];
                                        $testiurl = $custom["my_testi_url"][0];
                                        $testiinfo = $custom["my_testi_info"][0];
                                        ?>

                                    <div class="testi_item">

                                    <?php if($limittext=="" || $limittext==0){ ?>
                                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                    <?php }else{ ?>
                                        <?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo my_string_limit_words($excerpt,$limittext);?>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                     <div class="name-testi">
                                     <span class="user"><?php echo $testiname; ?></span>,
                                     <a href="http://<?php echo $testiurl; ?>"><?php echo $testiurl; ?></a><br/>
                                     <span class="info"><?php echo $testiinfo; ?></span>
                                     </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of testimonials -->



                        <?php } elseif($category=="portfolio"){ ?>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                jQuery(function(){
                                    jQuery('#slides').slides({
                                        effect: 'fade',
                                        crossfade: true,
                                        preload: true,
                                        generateNextPrev: true,
                                        autoHeight: true
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
                            <div id="slides">
                                <div class="slides_container">
                                    <?php $limittext = $limit;?>
                                    <?php global $more; $more = 0;?>
                                    <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=". $count ."&post_type=" . $category);?>
                                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

                                    <?php
                                    $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full'); //get img URL
                                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 250, 150, true ); //resize & crop img
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <?php if($limittext=="" || $limittext==0){ ?>
                                        <figure class="featured-thumbnail">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
                                        </figure>
                                        <?php }else{ ?>
                                        <figure class="featured-thumbnail">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
                                        </figure>
                                        <?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo my_string_limit_words($excerpt,$limittext); } ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- end of portfolio_cycle -->

                        <?php } else { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('#slider-code').tinycarousel({ axis: 'y'});

    });
</script>

<div id="slider-code">
    <a class="buttons prev" href="#">left</a>
    <div class="viewport">
        <ul class="overview">
                                    <?php $limittext = $limit;?>
                                    <?php global $more; $more = 0;?>
                                    <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=" . $count . "&post_type=" . $category);?>
                                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

                                    <?php 
                                        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                                        $period = $custom["period"][0];
                                    ?>

                                    <li>
                                        <?php if($limittext=="" || $limittext==0){ ?>
                                            <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                                            <b><?php echo $period; ?></b>
                                            <em><a href="#"><?php _e('view details', 'theme1831'); ?></a></em>
                                        <?php }else{ ?>
                                            <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                                            <b><?php echo $period; ?></b>
                                            <div class="excerpt"><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo my_string_limit_words($excerpt,$limittext); ?></div>
                                            <em><a href="#"><?php _e('view details', 'theme1831'); ?></a></em>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="buttons next" href="#">right</a>
</div>

                            <!-- end of post_cycle -->
                            <?php }?>
              <?php echo $after_widget; ?>
        <?php
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::update */
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {             
        return $new_instance;
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::form */
    function form($instance) {              
            $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
            $limit = esc_attr($instance['limit']);
            $category = esc_attr($instance['category']);
            $count = esc_attr($instance['count']);
    ?>
      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'theme1831'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></label></p>

      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('limit'); ?>"><?php _e('Limit Text:', 'theme1831'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('limit'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('limit'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $limit; ?>" /></label></p>
      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>"><?php _e('Posts per page:', 'theme1831'); ?><input class="widefat" style="width:30px; display:block; text-align:center" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('count'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $count; ?>" /></label></p>

      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>"><?php _e('Show profile link:', 'theme1831'); ?><br />

      <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('category'); ?>" style="width:150px;" > 
      <option value="testi" <?php echo ($category === 'testi' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Testimonials</option>
      <option value="portfolio" <?php echo ($category === 'portfolio' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Portfolio</option>
      <option value="" <?php echo ($category === '' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Blog</option>
      </select>
      </label></p>

      <?php 
    }

} // class Cycle Widget


?>
```

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE:**

I was unable to get the "My - Post Cycle" widget to work as I wanted it to, so I decided to use another one of the widgets that come with the theme ("My - Recent Post"). It doesn't look as nice as the other one, but it allows me to post posts off of one category. Maybe seeing the code, will allows someone to figure out how to make the first widget work like this one, but retain the style. Here is its code:

```
<?php
// =============================== My Recent Posts (News widget) ======================================
class MY_PostWidget extends WP_Widget {
    /** constructor */
    function MY_PostWidget() {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'My - Recent Posts');  
    }

  /** @see WP_Widget::widget */
    function widget($args, $instance) {     
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
                $category = apply_filters('widget_category', $instance['category']);
                $post_format = apply_filters('widget_post_format', $instance['post_format']);
                $linktext = apply_filters('widget_linktext', $instance['linktext']);
                $linkurl = apply_filters('widget_linkurl', $instance['linkurl']);
                $count = apply_filters('widget_count', $instance['count']);
                $sort_by = apply_filters('widget_sort_by', $instance['sort_by']);
                $excerpt_count = apply_filters('widget_excerpt_count', $instance['excerpt_count']);
        ?>
              <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
                  <?php if ( $title )
                        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>



                        <?php if($post_format == 'post-format-standard') { 

                            $args = array(
                                        'showposts' => $count,
                                        'category_name' => $category,
                                        'orderby' => $sort_by,
                                        'tax_query' => array(
                                         'relation' => 'AND',
                                            array(
                                                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                                                'field' => 'slug',
                                                'terms' => array('post-format-aside', 'post-format-gallery', 'post-format-link', 'post-format-image', 'post-format-quote', 'post-format-audio', 'post-format-video'),
                                                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                                            )
                                        )
                                        );

                        } else { 

                            $args = array(
                                'showposts' => $count,
                                'category_name' => $category,
                                'orderby' => $sort_by,
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                 'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => array($post_format)
                                    )
                                )
                            );

                        } ?>





                        <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

                                <ul class="latestpost">

                                <?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();?>

                                <li class="clearfix">
                                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                                        <?php
                                        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                                        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full'); //get img URL
                                        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 100, 100, true ); //resize & crop img
                                        ?>
                                        <figure class="featured-thumbnail">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
                                        </figure>
                                    <?php } ?>
                  <time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d\TH:i'); ?>"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></time>
                  <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php _e('Permanent Link to', 'theme1831');?> <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                    <?php if($excerpt_count!="") { ?>
                                    <div class="excerpt">
                  <?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo my_string_limit_words($excerpt,$excerpt_count);?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="link"><?php _e('Read more', 'theme1831'); ?></a>
                                </li>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                </ul>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>


                                <!-- Link under post cycle -->
                                <?php if($linkurl !=""){?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $linkurl; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $linktext; ?></a>
                                <?php } ?>


              <?php echo $after_widget; ?>

        <?php
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::update */
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {             
        return $new_instance;
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget::form */
    function form($instance) {              
      $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
            $category = esc_attr($instance['category']);
            $post_format = esc_attr($instance['post_format']);
            $linktext = esc_attr($instance['linktext']);
            $linkurl = esc_attr($instance['linkurl']);
            $count = esc_attr($instance['count']);
            $sort_by = esc_attr($instance['sort_by']);
            $excerpt_count = esc_attr($instance['excerpt_count']);
        ?>
      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'theme1831'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></label></p>

      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>"><?php _e('Category Slug:', 'theme1831'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('category'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" /></label></p>

            <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_format'); ?>"><?php _e('Post format:', 'theme1831'); ?><br />

      <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_format'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('post_format'); ?>" style="width:150px;" > 
            <option value="post-format-standard" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-standard' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Standard</option>
      <option value="post-format-aside" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-aside' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Aside</option>
            <option value="post-format-quote" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-quote' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Quote</option>
            <option value="post-format-link" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-link' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Link</option>
            <option value="post-format-image" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-image' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Image</option>
      <option value="post-format-gallery" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-gallery' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Gallery</option>
            <option value="post-format-audio" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-audio' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Audio</option>
            <option value="post-format-video" <?php echo ($post_format === 'post-format-video' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?> >Video</option>
      </select>
      </label></p>

      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sort_by'); ?>"><?php _e('Post order:', 'theme1831'); ?><br />

      <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sort_by'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sort_by'); ?>" style="width:150px;" > 
            <option value="date" <?php echo ($sort_by === 'date' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Date</option>
          <option value="title" <?php echo ($sort_by === 'title' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Title</option>
          <option value="comment_count" <?php echo ($sort_by === 'comment_count' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Comment Count</option>
          <option value="rand" <?php echo ($sort_by === 'rand' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Random</option>
      </select>
      </label></p>

      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>"><?php _e('Posts per page:'); ?><input class="widefat" style="width:30px; display:block; text-align:center" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('count'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $count; ?>" /></label></p>

            <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('excerpt_count'); ?>"><?php _e('Excerpt length (words):'); ?><input class="widefat" style="width:30px; display:block; text-align:center" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('excerpt_count'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('excerpt_count'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $excerpt_count; ?>" /></label></p>

             <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linktext'); ?>"><?php _e('Link Text:', 'theme1831'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linktext'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('linktext'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $linktext; ?>" /></label></p>

             <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linkurl'); ?>"><?php _e('Link Url:', 'theme1831'); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linkurl'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('linkurl'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $linkurl; ?>" /></label></p>
        <?php 
    }

} // class Widget
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the parameter `post_type` with `category_name` to the `query_posts()` function called inside the `widget` method.

```
<?php query_posts("posts_per_page=". $count . "&category_name=" . $category); ?>
```

Reference: [WP_Query Category Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Comment: Reviewing the posted reference, I used &cat and came up with this:

`<?php query_posts("posts_per_page=". $count . "&cat=" . $category); ?>`

and then

`<option value="" <?php echo ($category === '74' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Blog</option>`

Where '74' is the category id of the category I want to display. 

Unfortunately, it did not work. I am still seeing all of my blog posts, and not just the blog posts from category id == 74.

Comment: Why did you use `cat`? I used `category_name` because you're dealing with category slugs and not ids.

Comment: I figured id would be easier than slug; I changed it to the code you provided and came up with this: `<option value="" <?php echo ($category === 'category-slug' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Blog</option>` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It should be: `<option value="blog" <?php echo ($category === 'blog' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Blog</option>`. However you should try and go back to use the code provided in your question and make only the changes I suggested in my answer (to both `query_posts` calls, since it's called twice).

Comment: I noticed that it is actually called 3 times, I replaced all 3 instances with the code you provided, and then added `<option value="blog" <?php echo ($category === 'category-slug' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Blog</option>` and now the widget on the home page is completely blank, devoid of any posts.

Comment: `category-slug` should be the actual category slug. Try `<option value="" <?php echo ($category === '' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Blog</option>`, like it was on your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74380/discussion-between-gothamgator-and-d79).